# How to modify EXIF metadata for JPEG images using Coldfusion?

Tags: coldfusion, jpeg, exif

I am using Coldfusion to view images stored in the file system and I can READ the EXIF metadata of JPEGs, but I'd like to know if it is possible to modify this information and re-save the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that there are XMP and IPTC custom tags out there, I googled now and seems that javaloader.cfc + some java lib are your only sure option.

EDIT: Since I work on stock photography application I got interested and found this command line tool which could do the trick:

http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/

Comment: Yes, by clicking on the page you see "ExifTool is a platform-independent Perl library plus a command-line application for reading and editing meta information...". 

I added it to my answer because it's "command-line application", and you can call it from ColdFusion or Java if you need.