# generating thumbnails using CF8 cfimage tag - large filesize caused by image metadata

Tags: coldfusion, thumbnails, coldfusion-8, iptc

i'm building a small web app that will resize images to different pixel dimensions after they have been uploaded.

I am attempting to create 150px X 100px thumbnail from a 3mb jpg image, but am unable to get the filesize smaller than 68kb ( I would expect to generate a file between 4kb & 15kb file depending on compression type etc).

I have used the action="resize" method of the  tag & also used the ImageResize() & imageScaleToFit() functions but all these methods keep the exif & IPTC meta data intact (I am assuming this is what is keeping the thumbnail file as large as it is).

If I use an image without any metadata it resizes the thumbnail to a small filesize as expected.

Is there anyway I can strip the exif & IPTC metadata from the image to reduce the thumbnail size using any of CF8's built in image functions?

Comment: Is this useful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863548/how-to-modify-exif-metadata-for-jpeg-images-using-coldfusion

Comment: Sorry, didn't clarify in my question - this app is going to be hosted on shared hosting, so I wont have any access to running any system cmds or <cfexecute> tags.

Answer (score 3):

you can use the [Sanselan](http://commons.apache.org/sanselan/) Java library to remove EXIF and IPTC metadata. Here is a code sample using the *removeExifMetadata* from this library:

```
<cfscript>
// setup and init the Sanselan library
SanselanPath = arrayNew(1);
arrayAppend(SanselanPath, expandPath("sanselan\sanselan-0.97-incubator.jar"));
javaloader = createObject("component", "javaloader.JavaLoader").init(SanselanPath);

// setup your source and destination image
pathToInFile = ExpandPath("myImage.jpg");
pathToOutFile = ExpandPath("MyImagewoEXIF.jpg");
inFile = javaloader.create("java.io.FileInputStream").init(pathToInFile);
outFile = javaloader.create("java.io.FileOutputStream").init(pathToOutFile);

// create the exifRewriter 
exifRewriter = javaloader.create("org.apache.sanselan.formats.jpeg.exifRewrite.ExifRewriter").init();

// call the method removeExifMetadata
exifRewriter.removeExifMetadata(inFile,outFile);
outFile.close();
</cfscript>
```

You can do the same to remove IPTC meta data using *iptc.JpegIptcRewriter* and the *removeIPTC* method. You can verify using the CF functions ImageGetEXIFMetaData and ImageGetIPTCMetadata that everything has been removed.

Now I'm not sure that it will really reduce the file size, let me know :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new image the same dimensions as the thumbnail and use `ImagePaste` to paste in the thumbnail. ColdFusion does not preserve EXIF data with the paste operation.

Comment: I did come across this method while searching for answers - the problem is when I try this, it still retains the metadata regardless of whether I set the image with the metadata to image1 (base image) or image 2 (top pasted image).

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to, you could use the command line tool that is linked in the post that @Ciaran Archer linked above, and then write a bash command (*nix/Mac) or bat command (Windows) that runs the command and then use CFExecute to run that command.  I have never really worked with CFImage before or image metadata so I couldn't give you the proper code, but what I said will probably have the best performance, because you are exporting commands to the filesystem is made to do (work with files).

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:
Use

```
ImageWrite(imageObject,destination,0.9,true) returns small sized image (90% quality, overwrite="true")
```

instead of

```
ImageWrite(imageObject,destination,true,0.9) returns big sized image (quality="true" which is 1, overwrite="0.9" which is true)
```

Select quality ratio from 0 to 1 to reduce the file size.

Comment: not sure how you mean ? the imageWrite() function only accepts 3 parameters

Comment: ImageWrite(name, destination, quality, overwrite)
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-796c.html

So use it like I mention above.

Comment: Oh, in CF8 there is no last (overwrite) argument. But anyway you can set image quality like this
ImageWrite(name, destination, 0.9)