# How to ImageSetEXIFMetadata and ImageSetIPTCMetadata in ColdFusion?

Tags: image, coldfusion, metadata

ColdFusion 8, 9, & 10 provide [ImageGetEXIFMetadata](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6bcb.html) and [ImageGetIPTCMetadata](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6bca.html) functions for extracting image meta data thanks to [Drew Noakes](http://drewnoakes.com/code/exif/) according to this [source](http://cflove.org/2013/04/coldfusion-imagegetexifmetadata-error.cfm).

I'm looking for a way to easily set or edit image meta data.

Comment: have you seen this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863548/how-to-modify-exif-metadata-for-jpeg-images-using-coldfusion

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Sanselan](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-imaging/) Java Library. I explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5520444/generating-thumbnails-using-cf8-cfimage-tag-large-filesize-caused-by-image-met) how to remove ExifMetaData but you can also overwrite them easily. Project is now part of the [commons-imaging](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-imaging/index.html).