# How to inject metadata info to image file upload?

Tags: coldfusion

Dear ColdFusion baddies,

I would like to know if there is a way to add metadata info when I'm upload a picture through the CF!

e.g. you can do it through PhotoShop http://www.artsnova.com/x/Chicago-Artists-Coalition-email-metadata.jpg "Photoshop MetaData"

I suppose i can convert the picture to Base64, inject my info there and then write back to file:

```
<cfimage action="write" source="#ImageReadBase64(form.myBase64Image)#" destination="#filePath##fileName#">
```

I have noticed that there is in the JPG file the following Tags:

```
<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="Adobe XMP Core 5.3-c011 66.145661, 2012/02/06-14:56:27        ">
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
<rdf:Description rdf:about="" xmlns:xmp="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/" xmlns:aux="http://ns.adobe.com/exif/1.0/aux/" xmlns:photoshop="http://ns.adobe.com/photoshop/1.0/" xmlns:xmpMM="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/mm/" xmlns:stEvt="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/sType/ResourceEvent#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:xmpRights="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/rights/" xmp:Rating="0" xmp:CreatorTool="Adobe Photoshop CS6 (Windows)" xmp:ModifyDate="2014-06-20T11:59:38+02:00" xmp:CreateDate="2014-06-03T07:52:21" xmp:MetadataDate="2014-06-20T11:59:38+02:00" aux:SerialNumber="193020002656" aux:LensInfo="28/1 300/1 0/0 0/0" aux:Lens="28-300mm" aux:LensID="6" aux:LensSerialNumber="0000000000" aux:ImageNumber="0" aux:FlashCompensation="0/1" aux:Firmware="1.2.3" photoshop:DateCreated="2014-06-03T07:52:21.001" photoshop:LegacyIPTCDigest="3AB878C7DE3E2C7D46FA1D558A375445" photoshop:ColorMode="3" photoshop:ICCProfile="sRGB v1.31 (Canon)" xmpMM:DocumentID="F5AE03309FA9337F43EA71C52F6B6C0D" xmpMM:InstanceID="xmp.iid:4E811E5E61F8E31183E6DB5EA6C6987D" xmpMM:OriginalDocumentID="F5AE03309FA9337F43EA71C52F6B6C0D" dc:format="image/jpeg" xmpRights:WebStatement="http://www.mywebsite.com">
<xmpMM:History>
<rdf:Seq>
<rdf:li stEvt:action="saved" stEvt:instanceID="xmp.iid:274f1a37-ad8a-40d8-b5d2-03cea0cf8c52" stEvt:when="2014-06-04T16:44:12+01:00" stEvt:softwareAgent="Adobe Photoshop CC (Macintosh)" stEvt:changed="/"/>
<rdf:li stEvt:action="saved" stEvt:instanceID="xmp.iid:4E811E5E61F8E31183E6DB5EA6C6987D" stEvt:when="2014-06-20T11:59:38+02:00" stEvt:softwareAgent="Adobe Photoshop CS6 (Windows)" stEvt:changed="/"/>
</rdf:Seq>
</xmpMM:History>
<dc:rights>
<rdf:Alt>
<rdf:li xml:lang="x-default">This Picture is a Property of My Company</rdf:li>
</rdf:Alt>
</dc:rights>
</rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
</x:xmpmeta>
```

But if i add or change those info manualy, then the JPG is Corrupted!
Any ideas or approach will be much appreciated!
Regards

Comment: Here is Adam's post.  He has insight. http://cfmlblog.adamcameron.me/2013/07/getobjectmetadata.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no **trivial** way to edit image metadata with ColdFusion. You should use some 3rd party tool (using [cfexecute](http://help.adobe.com/livedocs/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_d-e_18.html) tag) or java library to perform this task. Look at these answers:

- [how-to-modify-exif-metadata-for-jpeg-images-using-coldfusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863548/how-to-modify-exif-metadata-for-jpeg-images-using-coldfusion)
- [how-to-imagesetexifmetadata-and-imagesetiptcmetadata-in-coldfusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15842707/how-to-imagesetexifmetadata-and-imagesetiptcmetadata-in-coldfusion)

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising!

Answer (score 0):

There is a function `ImageGetMetadata()` which gets the meta data but looking at the docs I can not see a setter.

This answer talks about some custom tags that may be able to help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2863843/1218040

Comment: Thanks for the help, the suggested tool is called through command line (not the best option for me).

I'm trying a workaround by doing..
<cffile action = "readBinary" file = "#filePath##filename#" variable = "aBinaryObj">
<cfset strBinary2String = toString(aBinaryObj)> <!--- Do Staff --->
<cfset strString2Base64 = toBase64(strBinary2String)>
<cfset myImage = ImageReadBase64(strString2Base64)>
<cfimage source="#myImage#" destination="C:\result.jpeg" action="write">

But CF doesn't like my conversion and i get **ColdFusion was unable to create an image from the specified source file.**

Comment: Do you need to `#expandPath(filePath)##filename#` ?