# How to remove exif info of an image

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

We have users upload images from mobile devices. They show up correctly in browser but when report is carried over to a pdf, they are tilted. PD somehow unable to interpret the file exif info correctly. So,if we want to strip out the file exif info after uploading, how we can do it? I tried by rewriting the image but that did not helped.

Comment: Last I checked the only options were to use an external tool, like a [java library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5520444/generating-thumbnails-using-cf8-cfimage-tag-large-filesize-caused-by-image-met) or create a new image by copying it. Don't know if that's changed in newer versions of CF.