# How to write image data such as title, comments, tags etc

Tags: php, coldfusion, exif, exiftool, exifworks

Looking for something either using a programming language such as PHP or a desktop utility to essentially write data to an image file.

We have folders that contain hundreds of files of images. The images are formatted in this way `ARTIST at EVENT by PHOTOGRAPHER` with the title of the folder being `EVENT`

We'd like to edit the attributes of the file as follows:

- Title: ARTIST at EVENT by PHOTOGRAPHER
- Comments: ARTIST at EVENT by PHOTOGRAPHER
- Copyright: COMPANYNAME
- Tags: ARTIST, EVENT, PHOTOGRAPHER, COMPANYNAME

It would be good if we had a tool to go through each folder and make the changes, alternatively doing it manually per folder wouldn't be an issue as long as it went through all the photos automatically.

The filename can be altered if needed to something like `ARTIST$EVENT$PHOTOGRAPHER` to make it easier to split?!?

Comment: Hmm - rather it not but if you got a solution that works, I'll be interested

Comment: i don't have this working. but can do. PM me and we talk more.

Comment: Probably not exactly what you're after but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863548/how-to-modify-exif-metadata-for-jpeg-images-using-coldfusion

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ended up using Adobe Bridge as I can't see there being any option with ColdFusion or PHP

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen this utility: http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/

It seems very powerful and was an accepted answer on StackOverflow prior: [How to modify EXIF metadata for JPEG images using Coldfusion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863548/how-to-modify-exif-metadata-for-jpeg-images-using-coldfusion)

Thanks,

Tim

Comment: Heh, I posted that link in a comment, probably when you were typing.